# Matplotlib - axvlines across subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to draw vertical lines across multiple subplots? Whatever I try `axvlines` are shown only in the bottom subplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, zx = plt.subplots(5,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,1,1,1,1]})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)

pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}).plot( grid = True, ax=zx[2])

for x_val in [2.25,3.25,4.25]:
    plt.axvline(x_val, color = 'green')

pd.DataFrame({'B':[6,5,4,3,2]}).plot( grid = True, ax=zx[3])

for x_val in [2.25,3.25,4.25]:
    plt.axvline(x_val, color = 'red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: don't use `plt.axvline`, use e.g., `zx[3].axvline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use axes, zx like this to draw line:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, zx = plt.subplots(5,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,1,1,1,1]})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)

pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]}).plot( grid = True, ax=zx[2])

for x_val in [2.25,3.25,4.25]:
    zx[2].axvline(x_val, color = 'green')

pd.DataFrame({'B':[6,5,4,3,2]}).plot( grid = True, ax=zx[3])

for x_val in [2.25,3.25,4.25]:
    zx[3].axvline(x_val, color = 'red')

plt.show()
```

[image]